# Android / Java : Show date from now

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I have a String like that : `String date_annonce = "2014-06-12 17:25:43";`

I would like to show in my app a text like : **10 min ago** or **1h ago** or **2d ago**

It represent the difference from date_annonce and actual date.

How can i do this ?

Comment: if you have got your answer than accept answer so other can get help from your contribution

Answer (score 3):

see this DateUtil method

[`getRelativeDateTimeString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29)

```
String relativeString = getRelativeDateTimeString (this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to subtract `System.currentTimeMillis()` from `data_annonce` in milliseconds. To convert it milliseconds you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to get a `Date` object from the string.

Comment: The OP would also have to do some rounding to the nearest time component (minute, hour, day, week, etc.) to create a nice representation.